# Adding row to an existing html table from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

more of newbies :)

I've created HTML table using below html code

```
 <table runat="server" id="Table1" border="1" class="style1">
    <tr>
        <td class="style2" colspan="3">
            Info.</td>
        <td class="style2" colspan="2">
            TypeA</td>
        <td class="style2">
            TypeB</td>
        <td class="style2" rowspan="2">
            TypeC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style3">
            Dept.</td>
        <td class="style3">
            Div.</td>
        <td class="style3">
            Unit</td>
        <td class="style3">
            TypeA.1</td>
        <td class="style3">
            TypeA.1</td>
        <td style="text-align: center">
            TypeB.1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I tried to add row for it using

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TableRow tRow = new TableRow();
    for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)
    {
        TableCell tb = new TableCell();
        tb.Text = "text";
        tRow.Controls.Add(tb);
    }
    Table1.Rows.Add(tRow);
}
```

but I got :

> The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRowCollection.Add(System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow)' has some invalid arguments

I googled around but with no luck.

I'm doing this to avoid Columns Heading merging action in code behind while I still have to look for how to merge rows heading. This is the last step for completing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670384/asp-net-dynamic-input-display-table-by-section-with-multi-columns-rows-headers

,.. closer heading view is:

[image]

Rows created will have a forwarding heading cell that should be merged if it's the same with row above. Appreaciate the great assistant from StackOverflow members.

Comment: not sure but may be the type of row should the existing table row. or the row should be three column

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is apparent in the exception.

You are using `TableRow` instead of `HtmlTableRow`.
Hover over `TableRow tRow = new TableRow();` to see which namespace is the `TableRow` class from.

A similar change for cell would be required. i.e. use `HtmlTableCell` instead of `TableCell`.

EDIT: `Table`, `TableRow` are classes from `System.Web.UI.WebControls` namespace.
Whereas, `HtmlTable`, `HtmlTableRow` are classes from `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls` namespace.

Comment: This is great brother Shahkalpesh... what an excellent knowlage . One small question, why it will not produce another row if I click the button again?!.. I also would take the advantage to ask you if you know how to merge rows if it's equel to previous row in the same column... you are really amzing guys.

Answer (score 1):

You just need more attention. You can try this:

Step 1:

```
<table runat="server" id="Table1" border="1" class="style1">
    <tr>
        <td class="style2" colspan="3">
            Info.</td>
        <td class="style2" colspan="2">
            TypeA</td>
        <td class="style2">
            TypeB</td>
        <td class="style2" rowspan="2">
            TypeC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style3">
            Dept.</td>
        <td class="style3">
            Div.</td>
        <td class="style3">
            Unit</td>
        <td class="style3">
            TypeA.1</td>
        <td class="style3">
            TypeA.1</td>
        <td style="text-align: center">
            TypeB.1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Step 2 : in code behind use this code:

```
 HtmlTableRow tRow = new HtmlTableRow();
 for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
 {
    HtmlTableCell tb = new HtmlTableCell();               
    tb.InnerText = "text";
    tRow.Controls.Add(tb);
 }
 Table1.Rows.Add(tRow);
```

Notice: Use this `using` in code behind:

```
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
```