# How can i insert a label text in a table cell

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a table which i am dynamically generating based on user input. I am trying to insert a label text into table cell on button click. onclick of button a label text of a demo method should be inserted into table cells. Can someone suggest me how can i do this?

Thanks.

Creating Table:

```
function CreateTable(){
    var rowCtr;
    var cellCtr;
    var rowCnt;
    var cellCnt;

    var myTableDiv = document.getElementById('myDynamicTable');

    var table = document.createElement('table');
    table.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
    table.border = "1";
    table.id = "myTable";


    var tableBody = document.createElement('tbody');
    table.appendChild(tableBody);

    rowCnt = document.getElementById('txtrows').value;
    cellCnt = document.getElementById('txtcols').value;

    for (rowCtr = 0; rowCtr < rowCnt; rowCtr++) {

        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tableBody.appendChild(tr);

        for (cellCtr = 0; cellCtr < cellCnt; cellCtr++) {

            var td = document.createElement('td');
            td.width = '120';
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Row:" + rowCtr + " Column:" + cellCtr));
            tr.appendChild(td);
        }
    }
    myTableDiv.appendChild(table);
  }
```

Button:

```
<asp:Button ID="button1" Text="button" runat="server" OnClick="demo" />
```

C# code:

```
 public void demo()
    {
        TableCell tcell = new TableCell();
        RadLabel rlbl = new RadLabel();
        rlbl.Text = "test";
        tcell.Controls.Add(rlbl);

    }

    protected void demo(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        demo();
    }
```

Comment: is there any requirement to do that from server side? You can do that easily from javascript

Comment: You cannot do it like this. You create the table with Jquery but want to add aspnet controls in code behind. That is not gonna work. Follow @ArunKumar 's comment and also add it client side.

Comment: Yes, i have to bind data from backend.

Comment: Try webmethod and Ajax to get back data in clientside

Comment: you have 2 options here, either create your whole table from code behind or use javascript/ajax to get your code behind value and then bind it to your html table

Comment: I have never used javscript/ ajax can you please explain, how can i use this?? @ArunKumar Thanks

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169636/adding-row-to-an-existing-html-table-from-code-behind

Comment: Any how, can i do this using javascript, thanks @ArunKumar

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give you a start using Javascript, you can use below code as a starting point.

```js
window.onload=function(){
CreateTable();
}
function CreateTable(){
    var rowCtr;
    var cellCtr;
    var rowCnt;
    var cellCnt;

    var myTableDiv = document.getElementById('myDynamicTable');

    var table = document.createElement('table');
    table.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
    table.border = "1";
    table.id = "myTable";


    var tableBody = document.createElement('tbody');
    table.appendChild(tableBody);

    rowCnt = 3; //document.getElementById('txtrows').value;
    cellCnt =2; //document.getElementById('txtcols').value;

    for (rowCtr = 0; rowCtr < rowCnt; rowCtr++) {

        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tableBody.appendChild(tr);

        for (cellCtr = 0; cellCtr < cellCnt; cellCtr++) {

            var td = document.createElement('td');
            td.width = '120';
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Row:" + rowCtr + " Column:" + cellCtr));
            tr.appendChild(td);
        }
    }
    myTableDiv.appendChild(table);
  }

function demo(){
var myTable=document.getElementById('myTable');
var cell=myTable.rows[0].cells[1];
var label = document.createElement('label');
label.id="lbl-"+cell.cellIndex;
label.innerText="This is label text";
cell.appendChild(label);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="demo()" value="Create Label" />
<div id="myDynamicTable"></div>
```